# Problems deploying sitecore site with web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api, .net-4.0, sitecore, autofac, sitecore6

I have a sitecore site (6.6) that uses webapi and autofac.  The site itself works fine, but when I try to go to any of the actions on an api controller I get the below issue.  I feel like I'm missing some configuration or a library but web.config and binaries look the same.  This is on .net 4.0 which I believe supports WebApi

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpRoutingDispatcher.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) +298
   System.Net.Http.DelegatingHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) +38
   System.Web.Http.HttpServer.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) +310
   System.Net.Http.HttpMessageInvoker.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) +99
   System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContextBase, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +203
   System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +48
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9048532
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +184
```

I'm baffled, any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Will

Comment: .NET 4.0 does not support WebApi (which ships with .NET 4.5) out of the box unless you have your web.config set up to support it, which I believe the NuGet package will do for you. Did you add WebApi to your project using NuGet?

Comment: I tried that, but it didnt work.  As a test I put up a basic webforms site, with the webapi package on the same server.  It worked fine.  I compared the differences in the web.config and the bin folder.  All the same.  Still baffled.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same setup and issue as this.

It was caused by running on Windows Server 2008, without extensionless URL support.

You can get it working by installing the [KB980368](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/980368) hotfix from Microsoft. This is included in Service Pack 2 if you're running Windows Server 2008R2.